# Filter a connected list- How to show all by default?

Tags: web-part, filter, connection

I have two lists embedded as individual webparts on my SP2010 page. The two lists are connected so that the first list can act as a filter for the second one- there is a column which is common between the two lists. The idea is that users can select one of the items in the first list and then the second list will refresh to show only items which are relevant to that selection.

I have got that working fine, but the problem is that when the page loads, it automatically applies a filter. By default, when the page loads, the first list is filtered to select the first item. This means that when a user opens the page, only items related to the first item are shown. This behaviour is not really ideal- I was hoping that the page would show all the items when the page loaded, and that the user could then decide to filter the list as they wanted.

Do you please have any suggestions on how I can change the default behaviour so that the page shows **all items** (ie, doesn't filter the list) when it loads?

Many thanks!
Jack

Ps in case it is relevant, I do not have Publishing functionality available to me :/